# MySQL search to ignore hyphens

Tags: mysql

How can I search for "1-800-flowers" by "1800flowers" in MySQL?

I have the data "1-800-flowers", but I want to find it by "1800flowers".

Comment: You can remove your hyphens before your data being passed to mysql like with php `str_replace($search_str, '-', '');`

Answer (score 6):

You're probably best off creating a second column that you fill with `1800flowers` (replacing all  characters you want to ignore) and searching that. That way, you can make full use of indexing.

A quick way to convert all existing data would be

```
UPDATE table SET columnname_without_hyphens = REPLACE(columnname, "-", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is just ignoring hyphens, I may suggest using `REPLACE` to eliminate them, like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE REPLACE(column, '-', '') ...
```

Otherwise, if you're looking for strings that "sound alike", you may want to have a look at the [`SOUNDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the replace function will kill any ability to use an index on the column, but:

```
select *
    from YourTable
    where replace(YourColumn, '-', '') = '1800flowers'
```