# How to remove hyphens using MySQL UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use mySQL replace() to replace strings in multiple records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records)
>   [MySQL search to ignore hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925791/mysql-search-to-ignore-hyphens)

What is the best way to remove hyphens from a field using mysql UPDATE without php?

```
field: 211-555-1212 > 2115551212
```

Comment: Google `mysql replace string`, 1st result

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271186/how-can-i-use-mysql-replace-to-replace-strings-in-multiple-records - May have your answer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) function, for `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET field = replace(field, '-', '')
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/367954/1)

For `SELECT`:

```
SELECT replace(field, '-', '') field
FROM yourtable
```